# javascript. Keep testing until true

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to constantly test something until it's true.
So everytime it's false the if statement is tested again.

I tried:

```
var repeat_until = 0;
while(repeat_until == 0) {
    if(a condition) {
        repeat_until = 1;
    }
}
```

but of course it didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: What is "a condition"? How does it change? What didn't work?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? is it because nothing is changing the state of the condition?

Comment: Also, your code is logically identical to `while(!(a condition));`

Comment: The condition works fine.... smh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend having some 10000 instructions executed in a single millisecond. So I would give a `setInterval` instead of `while` loop. Give a while loop here will be too costly bandwidth for the CPU Cycle as it is single thread. Check this out:

```js
$(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#console").prepend("<p>TEST: " + ($("input").is(":checked")) + "</p>");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
p {margin: 0 0 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks!
The problem was that the browser was freezing when trying to run the script. Didn't think making it wait would do that trick.

Comment: @Density Sure. Do you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Kurmar I had to wait, it wouldn't let me

Answer (score 1):

Because regular Javascript is single threaded, if you sit in a tight loop like this, no other Javascript can run and thus no other Javascript can ever change your `repeat_until` variable or influence your condition so thus the `while` loop turns into an infinite loop because no other code can ever run to create the condition you're waiting for.

If you explain precisely what the condition is that you are waiting for, then we can likely help with a better way to run some code when that condition has been met.  You may have to poll with `setInterval()` or there may be a direct notification of some event that you can use.  But, the right and best method for running some code when your condition is met depends entirely on what the condition is and what controls the condition changing.

For example, here's a solution that polls once per second that allows other code a chance to run:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (a condition) {
         clearInterval(interval);
         // do your other work here
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what `a condition` is. Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0aecfcng/

```
var repeat_until = 0;
var temp = 0;
while(repeat_until == 0) {
    if(temp >= 10) {
        repeat_until = 1;
    }
    temp += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/s6Lt96kp/5/

```
function change(){
    var value = false;
    var a = 0;
    while(value == false ) {
        if(a==4) {
            value = true;
        } else {
           a++;
        }
    }
}
```